# How to load specific Excel sheets?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would like to know if there is a function to load sheets specific with Python in a excel, for example if I have 34 sheets load only the first 25 sheets. With the following line I load all the sheets.

```
xlsx=pd.ExcelFile('archivo.xlsx')
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
sheet_names = xl.sheet_names #get all the sheet names
```

if you want grab first 40 sheets from your excel file ,

```
sheets = sheet_names[:40]
```

If you want to load specific sheet just pass it as the second argument, In this case it is a list of sheet names.

```
data= pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xlsx', sheet_name=sheets )
```

## Note:

This will return the dictionary type output. Here you can get an idea about [how to convert python dict to pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameter `sheet_name`

```
df= pd.read_excel('Excel_File.xlsx', sheet_name="SheetName")
```

[Refer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

The parameter value can be anyone from below

1. Sheet Name
2. Sheet Number

Available cases:

> - Defaults to  0: 1st sheet as a DataFrame
>        1: 2nd sheet as a DataFrame
> - "Sheet1": Load sheet with name “Sheet1”
> - [0, 1, "Sheet5"]: Load first, second and sheet named “Sheet5” as a    dict of DataFrame
> - None: All sheets.